# What does "the LCM of two distinct positive integers is divisible by the highest single digit power of 3 , while their HCF is 12. " mean?

Tags: divisibility, factoring, gcd-and-lcm

> The LCM of two distinct positive integers is divisible by the highest single digit power of 3 , while their HCF is 12. Which of the following could be the smaller of the two?

I think this means the LCM is divisible by $3^9$ but their HCF is 12.

So, one is $3 \cdot 2^2$, another is $3^{8+x} \cdot 2^2$ where $x \geq 0$?

A. 6

B. 24

C. 36

D. 300

E. 360

I heard B, and D are both correct but I don't see why.

Comment: That is very strange phrasing indeed.  Like you, I would guess that this means that $3^9$ divides $\text {lcm}(a,b)$ but I wouldn't feel very confident about it.

Comment: I believe it means $9=3^2|\ldots$ not $3^9 | \ldots$

Comment: Your classification of the solutions is incomplete though (given the reading of the constraint you employ). First of all, you need one term to be divisible by $3^9$, whereas your expression only guarantees $3^8$.  Secondly, you can multiply both terms by anything you want (so long as the two multipliers are relatively prime).

Comment: @BenjaminWang  Yes, that's another possible reading.  Perhaps there are others.  Such an odd way to phrase a (presumably) simple constraint.

Comment: If the problem was assigned by a teacher, then your posting is misdirected.  It is up to the teacher to resolve ambiguities.

Comment: @BenjaminWang  With that reading, however, $C$ would also be possible.  You could have the pair $(36, 3\times 2^2\times 5)$.  For that pair we see that, indeed, the lcm is divisible by $9$ and that the gcd is $12$.  With the other reading, $C$ is excluded since $9$ would clearly divide the gcd.